# import data from Excel file into the SQL table without duplicates?

Tags: sql, excel, azure, import

How to import data from Excel file into the windows azure SQL table without duplicates?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What does the structure of your data look like and what code are you trying to execute to load from the file(maybe external table) into another table?

Comment: If you plan on importring to the rdbms without mutating the excel file, then please share your code and the rdbms youre using

Comment: @marc_s: SQL Server 2012

Comment: @ShreyasChavan: SQL Server 2012, I have several Excel files and need to push that data into the relevant SQL tables without duplicating. It include columns like Company Name, Contact Person, Address...

Comment: Is it possible by using Cursor? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel (2007 for me), Data->Remove Duplicates->specify which columns to look at. You can also make a primary key in your SQL table, and when you're inserting all your records from Excel any duplicates will fail to go in.